# Accessing SharePoint 2013 using C# 64-bit

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I've been developing for SharePoint for roughly 2 weeks and I keep running across the same problem. How do I successfully access SPWeb object? Here's my issue:

If I try to access SPWeb (SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web) I get an error message: "Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable."

Ok, no problem. So, I change my Project AND my Web Project to x64 under Properties -> Build -> Platform target.

Now when I run the application I get the following error: "Could not load file or assembly 'xxxWeb' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

I've tried many things and this is a right-out-of-the-box solution. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Image of error information (may need to zoom in):

[image]

Comment: Hi Brian
What kind of application did you create (Console, WinForms, WebPart, App)?
As you found out SharePoint requires 64-bit build, but it looks like one of the assemblies you referenced is not compatible with 64 bit.
What I would try is:
- Remove the assemblies and relink them to your project after you changed it to 64 bit.

Comment: This is an App. I'll give your suggestion a try (after a backup) ;) Thanks

Comment: No luck, it doesn't seem to be related to the DLLs I am referencing. The error mentions something about binding to a partial assembly name.